# What is "MediaTek Preloader USB VCOM Port" driver for?

Tags: windows-10, usb, flashing

We have **two** Windows 10 drivers to connect to "MTK phone" using USB when it is off: "MediaTek Preloader USB VCOM Port" and "MediaTek USB Port".

Sometimes my device is recognized only as "MediaTek Preloader USB VCOM Port" - when I expect - "MediaTek USB Port" - I do not understand why and do not see any system in that. It bothers me.

Generally why we need "MediaTek Preloader USB VCOM Port" driver? May be it can be uninstalled.